# Android Studio CardView with two columns that have equal width

Tags: java, android, android-studio, multiple-columns, cardview

I am trying to display in a cardview two elements on each row ( two columns ). However, they are not centered in the cardview. [click here to see how the cardview displays items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s7XO.jpg)

Here is the code in the xml.:

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FFDB78"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutCateg"
            android:layout_above="@+id/menu"
            android:id="@+id/currentCategoryRecyclerView"/>
```

I create a new GridLayoutManager in the Main activity, programatically, like this:

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(CategoryListActivity.this,2));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryRecycler);
```

The cardview is in a Relative Layout that has the `"android:gravity="center"` property, if that matters.
I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Provide your cardview xml. Possibly the `android:layoutWidth` and `android:layoutHeight` attributes need to be changed.

Comment: thank you for your advice. However, Ganesh's solution works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem as you, I found the `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration` class for **RecyclerView Spacing**.

```
public class ItemOffsetDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private int mItemOffset;

public ItemOffsetDecoration(int itemOffset) {
    mItemOffset = itemOffset;
}

public ItemOffsetDecoration(@NonNull Context context, @DimenRes int itemOffsetId) {
    this(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(itemOffsetId));
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
        RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
    outRect.set(mItemOffset, mItemOffset, mItemOffset, mItemOffset);
}
```

}

Add `ItemOffsetDecoration` to your RecyclerView. 
Item **offset** value should be half size of the actual value you want to add a space between items.

```
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, NUM_COLUMNS);
ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(context, R.dimen.item_offset);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
```

Also, set item **offset** value as padding for its RecyclerView, and specify `android:clipToPadding=false`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recyclerview_grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:padding="@dimen/item_offset"/>    <!--Give a desired size-->
```

[refer](https://gist.github.com/yqritc/ccca77dc42f2364777e1)